# How do I parse media files without the extension in Python 3 without getting blank result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the most recent media file (movie) in a particular folder...but finding it hard to extract the title without the extension.

Here's my code:

```
import os
import glob

def fileOpener():
    """ This function opens my systems movie folder
    Selects all mp4 extensions that were last modified
    and parses the title...so it can be used to search
    IMDB"""

    movies = glob.glob('PATHTOMOVIES/Videos/NEW/*')
    latestMovie = max(movies, key=os.path.getmtime)
    movieTitle = os.path.split(lastestMovie)[0]

fileOpener()
```

My result:

```
<BLANK STARE>
```

How do I solve this please?

Thanks.

***NB:*** *I use a windows machine running Windows 8.1.*

Comment: aren't you supposed to _return_ `movieTitle` ?

Comment: Did you try to put the full path to the folder?

Comment: Yep! I tried the full path. Also to print the movie title variable in shell but got the path:  <code>'PATHTOMOVIES/Videos/NEW/'</code> without the movie.

Comment: May I add that, I printed out the movieTitle var and got the path and movie in a head, tail list. The problem is when I try to access the list with [0]. It returns blank a result

Comment: Hmm...when I run it [0] returns the parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have typo in your code in the last line of fileOpener().
2. You are assigning the folder name to movieTitle, not the file name.
3. Your fileOpener() function doesn't do or return anything.